# Swift 4 - Setter for 'webView' with Objective-C selector 'setWebView:' conflicts with setter for 'WebView' with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: swift, wkwebview

When i tried to create a wkwebview that appeared this error hint, do not know how to fix it.

```
var webView: WKWebView!
```

[Xcode Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxlBA.png)

[The last part of the picture is covered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P6ar.png)

Comment: Can you share the line that's covered by the header?

Comment: @NSAdi shure, https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P6ar.png

Comment: I have found the problem, when I no longer use the "webView" named when the return to normal.